# Using spark-cassandra-connector-java api and get error when attempting to submit a spark job

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark, spark-cassandra-connector

So I'm trying to get a simple example program working using Java and spark cassandra connector. Running sbt assembly works fine and I get a fat jar that I submit to spark. The problem comes here, when I submit the job to spark I get this error:

```
vagrant@cassandra-spark:~$ source submit-job.sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/japi/CassandraJavaUtil
    at JavaTest.main(JavaTest.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 10 more
```

This is the submit-job.sh script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
~/spark/bin/spark-submit --driver-class-path ~/JavaTest/lib/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.3.0-M2-SNAPSHOT.jar ~/JavaTest/target/scala-2.10/CassSparkTest-assembly-1.0.jar
```

This is my build.sbt file

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
        settings(
                name := "CassSparkTest",
                version := "1.0"
        )
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "2.1.5" % "provided",
        "org.apache.cassandra" % "cassandra-thrift" % "2.1.5" % "provided",
        "org.apache.cassandra" % "cassandra-clientutil" % "2.1.5" % "provided",
        //"com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.3.0-M1"  % "provided",
        "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector-java" % "1.3.0-M1" % "provided",
        "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.3.1" % "provided",
        "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.3.1" % "provided",
        "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.3.1" % "provided",
        "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.4" % "provided"
)
```

Below is the code being compiled:

```
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.*;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraRow;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class JavaTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1");
                JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext("spark://192.168.10.11:7077", "test", conf);
                JavaRDD<String> cassandraRowsRDD = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("ks", "test")
                        .map(new Function<CassandraRow, String>() {
                                @Override
                                public String call(CassandraRow cassandraRow) throws Exception {
                                        return cassandraRow.toString();
                                }
                        });
                System.out.println("Data as CassandraRows: \n" + StringUtils.join(cassandraRowsRDD.toArray(), "\n"));

        }
}
```

sbt assembly works fine but the class definition isn't found once the job is actually submitted.

Comment: Check your spark-cassandra-connector version

Answer (score 0):

When I had hit this before I had to add the current class jar to the SparkConf.  For example:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1");

conf.setJars(SparkContext.jarOfObject(this))
```

Comment: I added conf.setJars(JavaSparkContext.jarOfClass(JavaTest.class)); and I still got the same error